# Is there any method to create gzip compressed file with zlib?

Tags: methods, compression, gzip, zlib, deflate

I've done to make gzip compressed file with deflateInit2, deflate, deflateEnd of zlib in c source code. But, the output is different from the original one that made through 'gzip -f -n -9 *file-name*' command.

Are there any other methods to make the completely same?

- additional situation descriptions -
  my implementation sample is like below...

  1. deflateInit2(&strm, 9, Z_DEFLATED, 31, 9, Z_DEFAULT_STRATEGY);
  2. deflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
  3. deflateEnd(&strm);

but, the result is different from the middle. Until the offset 0x90656 of compressed image from my apis is the same.
the original compressed image size is 6,739KB but, the compressed image size from my apis is about 6,743KB.

Comment: Check if you can decompress it via command line. And compare the resulting file with the original

Comment: yes, I 've been doing so. but, decompressed things are the same completely. I don't know how to make the compressed things the same exactly.

Comment: The idea is to decompress it with `gzip`. The difference can come from level of compresion

Comment: Exactly what I'm saying is that the compressed file by my implementing compression api is different from the other by command 'gzip -f -n -9 file-name'. in this case, both decompressed files are the same with original. compression level is the same to 9